# Cannot connect to Oracle Db

Tags: oracle

Hi I am receiving this error when I am trying to connect to the Oracle DB

I already tried reconnecting the DB again and again and also tried to close and open the application again

Here is the Stack trace of error I am getting

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CCallableStatement.isClosed()Z is abstract
    at
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.isClosed(T4CCallableStatement.java)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.proxy.driver.oracle.RaptorProxyOJDBCStatement$StatementCloser.close(RaptorProxyOJDBCStatement.java:61)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.proxy.ProxyContext.referentDequeued(ProxyContext.java:248)
    at
oracle.dbtools.util.GCTracker.handlePendingReap(GCTracker.java:109)
    at oracle.dbtools.util.GCTracker.track(GCTracker.java:60)   at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.proxy.AbstractProxy.initialize(AbstractProxy.java:49)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.proxy.AbstractProxy.initialize(AbstractProxy.java:59)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.proxy.AbstractProxy.getProxyContext(AbstractProxy.java:131)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.proxy.ProxyUtils.formatArg(ProxyUtils.java:72)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.proxy.ProxyLogger.logPostForAll(ProxyLogger.java:221)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.proxy.ProxyLogger.stateChanged(ProxyLogger.java:48)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.proxy.MethodTracker.fireStateChanged(MethodTracker.java:103)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.proxy.MethodTracker.access$900(MethodTracker.java:18)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.proxy.MethodTracker$CallMetrics.setState(MethodTracker.java:280)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.proxy.MethodTracker$CallMetrics.access$400(MethodTracker.java:236)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.proxy.MethodTracker.methodReturned(MethodTracker.java:178)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.proxy.AbstractProxy.methodCompleted(AbstractProxy.java:122)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.proxy.AbstractProxy.methodReturned(AbstractProxy.java:97)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.proxy.driver.oracle.RaptorProxyOJDBCConnection.postFor_prepareCall(RaptorProxyOJDBCConnection.java:294)
    at
oracle.jdbc.proxy.oracle$1dbtools$1raptor$1proxy$1driver$1oracle$1RaptorProxyOJDBCConnection$2oracle$1jdbc$1internal$1OracleConnection$$$Proxy.prepareCall(Unknown
Source)
at
oracle.dbtools.db.OracleUtil.checkAccessImpl(OracleUtil.java:446)
at
oracle.dbtools.db.DBUtil.checkAccess(DBUtil.java:1815)
at
oracle.dbtools.db.AccessCache.checkAccess(AccessCache.java:64)
at
oracle.dbtools.db.AccessCache.hasAccess(AccessCache.java:55)
at
oracle.dbtools.db.AccessCache.hasAccess(AccessCache.java:24)
at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.query.QueryUtils.checkNonOracleAccess(QueryUtils.java:610)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.query.QueryUtils.getQuery(QueryUtils.java:410)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.query.QueryUtils.getQuery(QueryUtils.java:329)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.query.ObjectQueries.getQuery(ObjectQueries.java:46)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.xml.XmlObjectFactory.createFolderInstance(XmlObjectFactory.java:63)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.xml.XmlTypeOwnerInstance.listTypeFolders(XmlTypeOwnerInstance.java:93)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.impl.TypeContainerTreeNode.loadTypeFolders(TypeContainerTreeNode.java:121)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.impl.DatabaseTreeNode$LoadTask.doWork(DatabaseTreeNode.java:190)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.impl.DatabaseTreeNode$LoadTask.doWork(DatabaseTreeNode.java:119)
    at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at
oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:702)
    at
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: How are you trying to connect? Is it your own java code? Is it Oracle's _SQL Developer_? Something else?

Comment: Are you using Oracle [Raptor](https://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/271267.htm) ?

Comment: I am using ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER

Comment: This sounds like [a driver incompatibility](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3954341). Check the version of SQL Developer you are using, the version of the database, and that the two are compatible. If you're on an old version then maybe try [the current one](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html).

Comment: Okay thanks will give it a try